# How to achieve `EditorGUI.HelpBox` look with `GUIStyle`?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, editor, inspector

I'm writing a `DecoratorDrawer` that allows to give long, meaningfull descriptions for any field in the inspector. I'm aiming for a look like this:
[image]
(faked in gimp)

That is want a bit lighter background, a rounded border etc.

There are places in the Editor that use this style, for example there are two instances in the lightmapping window:
[image: lightmaper window with widget look selected]

I can't use `EditorGUI.HelpBox` because:

1. I cannot reliably measure the height of contents of the `HelpBox`. Note that the drawers forbid using `EditorGUILayout`.
2. There is no rich text or other way to style the content
3. Images aren't permited - i'd like to have them as an option later on

Using `HelpBox` it looks like this:

[image]

---

My question is: is there a hardcoded `GUIStyle` or `UnityEditor`/`UnityEditorInternal` method that allows for displaying information in this style? If not, any idea on how to fake this style? How to make the rounded corners? Remember that there is a pro skin that looks different, so it'd be nice if the solution would work on both skins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can retrieve the HelpBox style by getting it from `GUI.skin`.

Something like

```c#
EditorGUILayout.TextArea("This is my text", GUI.skin.GetStyle("HelpBox"));
```

will get you

[image]

Note that this will still not allow you to have rich text though. It's disabled by default. To enable it, you can do something like

```c#
GUIStyle myStyle = GUI.skin.GetStyle("HelpBox");
myStyle.richText = true;

EditorGUILayout.TextArea("This is my text <b>AND IT IS BOLD</b>", myStyle);
```

which will result in

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've found is by passing EditorStyles.helpBox to the constructor.

```
style = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.helpBox);
style.richText = true;
```

This way, you wont affect EditorStyles.helpBox by making changes to the style.